# How can i filter a dataframe's rows by specific bins

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
col1  col2
15    2
17    4
14    5
20    10
21    11
19    11
18    12
20    6
22    7
21    8
22    8
25    6
21    7
```

First, I use `pandas.value_counts()` for `col2` and I use three bins `(0,5] (5,10] (10,15]`.

Then, I want to filter the rows where the `col2` values belong to the first two bins with the highest frequency, in this case bins `(5,10]` and `(10,15]`.

Comment: please show us your desired data set...

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
s = df.col2.value_counts(bins=[0,5,10,15]).nlargest(2)
df[pd.cut(df.col2, s.index).notnull()]
```

output:

```
    col1  col2
3     20    10
4     21    11
5     19    11
6     18    12
7     20     6
8     22     7
9     21     8
10    22     8
11    25     6
12    21     7
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `bins` argument to `value_counts`!

Comment: @piRSquared me either !

Comment: Shhhh!  Me either, then the OP made reference to it, so I looked at the docs. :-)  And, this is why I love SO.

Comment: same here ... :-)

Answer (score 4):

This would be so easier to explain if you added the bin indicator for each row to be able to filter based on it. it can be done without this, but again, this would be easier to explain.

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'A': [15, 17, 14, 20, 21, 19, 18, 20, 20, 22, 21, 22, 25, 21],
                  'B': [2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 8, 6, 7, 12]})

bins = [0, 5, 10, 15]
DF['bins'] = pd.cut(DF.B, bins, right=False) #Adding the bins
```

You have to `right=False` to get the intervals (0, 5], (5, 10)..etc.

Then filter the column `DF.bins` that has values in the largest value counts element that you want.

```
DF[DF.bins.isin(DF.bins.value_counts().index[:2])]
```

the calling of `.index` to get a list of the largest bins, and the `[:2]` to get the highest 2 ranking bins.

```
    A   B   bins
2   14  5   [5, 10)
3   20  10  [10, 15)
4   21  11  [10, 15)
5   19  11  [10, 15)
6   18  12  [10, 15)
7   20  6   [5, 10)
8   20  7   [5, 10)
9   22  8   [5, 10)
10  21  8   [5, 10)
11  22  6   [5, 10)
12  25  7   [5, 10)
13  21  12  [10, 15)
```

If you would like to do this without adding a new column, follow [Floydian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4465203/floydian) answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should filter the dataframe based on a Boolean index using the bins:

```
top_2 = pd.value_counts(df.col2, bins=[0, 5, 10, 15]).nlargest(2)
df[~pd.cut(df.col2, top_2.index).isnull()]
```

output:

```
    col1  col2
3     20    10
4     21    11
5     19    11
6     18    12
7     20     6
8     22     7
9     21     8
10    22     8
11    25     6
12    21     7
```